# How to prevent loopback publish when mosquitto bridged with RabbitMQ MQTT?

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, mosquitto, bridge, broker

I have two mosquitto brokers installed on PC1 (mosquitto v1.4.8) and PC2 (RabbitMQ v3.6.2 with MQTT Adapter).

Bridging initiated at PC1 like below

```
sensor/room1/ <-> office/room1/
```

But I noticed there is always a duplicate message being published back whenever the bridge is active, means all my application (on PC1) which subscribes to the same topic will receives the same message twice. **What setting I did wrong here?**

PC1 mosquitto.conf

```
connection bridge-pc1-to-pc2
address pc2-address.com
topic room1/# both 2 sensor/ office/

bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
notifications true
cleansession true
try_private false
```

To test loopback issue, I had PC1 subscribed to topic `sensor/#`

```
mosquitto_sub -t sensor/# -v -d
```

Then at PC1 I publish a test message

```
mosquitto_pub -t sensor/room1/temperature -m '{"value":27.3, "timestamp":"2016-06-03 14:02:38"}'
```

Broker at cloud (PC2) received the message correctly (message received only once)

```
Client mosqsub/3121-Dennis-iMa sending CONNECT
Client mosqsub/3121-Dennis-iMa received CONNACK
Client mosqsub/3121-Dennis-iMa sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: office/#, QoS: 0)
Client mosqsub/3121-Dennis-iMa received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 1): 0
Client mosqsub/3121-Dennis-iMa received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'office/room1/temperature', ... (14 bytes))
office/room1/temperature {"value":27.3, "timestamp":"2016-06-03 14:02:38"}
```

But PC1 received the same message twice! Below is the Pi's output

```
Received CONNACK
Received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 1): 0
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'sensor/room1/temperature', ... (14 bytes))
sensor/room1/temperature {"value":27.3, "timestamp":"2016-06-03 14:02:38"}
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'sensor/room1/temperature', ... (14 bytes))
sensor/room1/temperature {"value":27.3, "timestamp":"2016-06-03 14:02:38"}
```

Why there is loopback published message and how to solve this?

**Update 3 Jun 2016**
This is not the same question with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283197/mqtt-mosquitto-bridge-horizontal-scaling), as it does not involve horizontal scaling (1-to-many brokers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mqtt mosquitto bridge horizontal scaling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283197/mqtt-mosquitto-bridge-horizontal-scaling)

Comment: @hardillb This is not the same question with this question, as it does not involve horizontal scaling (1-to-many brokers)

Answer (score 1):

Change `try_private false` to `try_private true`. This is exactly what it is intended for. If rabbit doesn't support that feature (it is currently not in the spec, but widely used) then you're out of luck.

Comment: i tried, it work if both brokers are mosquitto, but it doesn't work for mosquito + RabbitMQ

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ doesn't support `try_private` and doesn't know anything about the bridge. So messages published to `office/*` in RabbitMQ will be sent back to subscribed mosquitto without taking to account any `private` flags.
To remove cycles you can use different topic names for in and out connections or use two mosquitto servers.

Comment: changing my topic structure will be a lot of work now. I initially choose RabbitMQ because is free and support cloud clustering. Do you know any other brand which can do the same?