# Benchmark of mosquitto clustering?

Tags: cluster-computing, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to build an mosquitto clustering, because mosquitto is single thread and seems cannot handle lots of qos 2 messages.

MQTT server comparison: [Benchmark of MQTT Servers](http://www.scalagent.com/IMG/pdf/Benchmark_MQTT_servers-v1-1.pdf)

I found mosquitto can use bridge way to build cluster ([Cluster forming with Mosquitto broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280208/cluster-forming-with-mosquitto-broker#answer-36377681)), but I'm wondering if mosquitto subscribe all message from all other server will cause high overhead for internal message sending.

For example, if I have 10 mosquitto brokers, each of them serve 1,000 messages, originally it's total 10,000 messages. But messages will shared between brokers, so each message will send to another 9 brokers, that's a total 1,000 x 9 x 10 = 90,000 message for internal usage.

Is there some benchmark for mosquitto clustering? Or what's the general solution for sending lots of qos 2 messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We used to setup a MQTT service platform which use Mosquitto as the broker, with 8 brokers bridged together, about 20k clients subscribed with 20k topics, qos=0, avg pubs 1k messages/sec with 100-2k bytes, the bridge subscribe and publish all the topics, and bring a huge forward latency, sometimes more then 2 mins.
So now we simply broadcast all the pubs to each of the broker, this does work.
But bridge is something else with cluster, which means it does not like a logic MQTT broker that support cluster session, load balance, single point of failure,..
so I have implemented a autonomous Mosquitto cluster, and did some performance test by Tsung, generally speaking, with a scenario that 30k subscriber/2.5k pubs/sec, payload length=744bytes, qos=1, average request response is a bit high then bridge(5.1ms vs 2.32ms), but no message lost and the load did balanced.
you can find the detailed test report under [mosquitt-cluster-bridge-benchmark](https://github.com/hui6075/mosquitto-cluster/tree/master/benchmark).